# Preventing direct access to a route

Tags: angular

The Angular docs are nice, but can get a bit overwhelming, so maybe I missed this, but I'm trying to figure out how to prevent direct access to a route.

For example, I have a login route. I have a `canActivate` guard on it, which is working fine for now, but when someone goes directly to my `/login` route, it loads fine; canActivate seems to only prevent navigating to the route via a `routerLink`.

How can I best prevent access to certain routes overall? Obviously, I can always add code into the `onInit` functions of a component, but that's a lot of duplicate code (between guards, resolves, and then inits). I considered using Resolves, though I don't know when they fire, and as I can't see any way to make component specific resolves, this could mean a number of Resolves being created.

Any advice?

Comment: Are you missing the word "not" in this part of the sentence? "but when someone goes directly to my /login route, it loads fine, as of course, canActivate prevents navigating to the route." Are you saying canActivate does correctly prevent access to this route or that it doesn't?

Comment: Ah, I see how that is confusing. If someone navigates to the route via a routerLink, canActivate seems to stop it. If someone types the URL in directly, `localhost:4200/login`, the component can still be accessed.